# Are every main activities exported to another applications?

Tags: android-intent

Activities which has intent filter can be triggered by explicit Intent from another application.

Then, are every main activities which has an intent filter, such as action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN", category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER", exported to another applications?

Does it mean that every main activities are vulnerable to another application?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, inter-application communication is guided by the abstracted Linux kernel on top of which Java stack is built up, to comprise the Android platform. This underlying Linux kernel, to a certain extent, does monitor each call from an application layer which has to deal with data not associated with the invoking application itself.

Refer : [An Empirical Evaluation of the Android Security Framework-Alessandro Armando, Alessio Merlo, Luca Verderame](http://www.ai-lab.it/merlo/slides/SEC-2013-slides.pdf)

Secondly, importing the intent, in true sense, doesn't allow the application which has access to the intent of the other application, to access other data or features associated with the external application based on merely the intent filter associated with it.

Hope this helps.